# Would replacing a borrowed used towel with a new one be considered ribbis?

Tags: halacha, lending-interest-ribbis

Suppose someone was a guest at someone else's house, and he spilled something (stain causing) on the floor of his host's house, and he borrowed a towel telling the host that he will use it to wipe up the mess and he would replace it afterward with a new towel (due to the stain on the borrowed towel which could not be removed).

As long as the borrower clearly told the host that he will be using the towel for himself, and he will not be returning the same towel but another one, this is called "הלואה", borrowing with intent to return another item, money etc. where the laws of ribbis apply, rather than "שאלה", borrowing with intent to return the same item, where the laws of ribbis do not apply.

May he replace it with a new one, or would this be a problem of ribbis, since the towel he borrowed was a used towel and the new one, which he is replacing it with, is more valuable than the used towel?

Is this considered payment for damages done. [There is no prohibition of ribbis (according to most poskim) when paying (on time) for damages].

Comment: Why would you think this wouldn’t be an issue?